# How to find an item in a collection on a known index?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to find an item in a collection on a fix index.
i can remove an item like this

```
  my_Order.OrderItems.RemoveAt(id - 1);
```

But i want to know this item in a variable before deleting how can i find this?

```
  FoodItem fd= my_Order.OrderItems.
```

Comment: `OrderItems[index]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the collection exposes an indexer, you could use it:

```
 var element = my_Order.OrderItems[id -1]
```

If the collection does not expose an indexer you could use `Enumerable.ElementAt()`:

```
 var element = my_Order.ElementAt(id -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FoodItem fd = my_Order.OrderItems[id - 1];
```

Comment: Collection may not implement indexer.